# Use dropdown list to trigger operation to different controller

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, sails.js

I would like to use angularjs to create a table with a drop down list contains different operation and one cloumn of checked box. Once checked box is selected, different operation
The table is pretty much like airflow tables with variables. once secret_password box is selected based on "**Withselected**" tab execute different operation.
However should I created the table?

[image: table example]

Comment: Are you using ui routing?

Comment: No, i just would like to trigger some function in controller that running different shell command line and returncommand lieresult back up url